# Exception: Google is not defined [Cordova geolocation]

Tags: javascript, html, api, cordova, google-maps

I am trying to make a simple app that show me where I am on google maps API. 
I am using Cordova. 
 I build it for browser, and works fine, but when I build for android or windows, it builds but when I run it, the app opens but does not work.

It show me a warning saying that Google is not defined.
 
Look at the attached photo: [Warning error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kEda.png)

HERE IS MY JS CODE:

var app = {

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError);
},

onSuccess: function(position){

    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: latLong,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLong,
          map: map,
          title: 'my location'
      });
},

onError: function(error){
    alert("cod erro " + error.code + ". \n" + 
        "mensagem: " + error.message);
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

Place this script at the end of your HTML document (**replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual API key**)

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

In this script the callback is called initMap(). It would look something like this :

```
function initMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){ 
         getGeoLocation();
     });
}

 // Gets user location
function getGeoLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            // Gets lat & lng and makes a LatLng object
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Places a marker on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLong,
                map: map,
                title: 'my location'
            });

            // Centers map on user location
            map.setCenter({lat:latitude, lng:longitude});

        }, geoLocationError, {maximumAge:600000, timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried without success. Please look at my js code. I edited the post with my code, please have a look, thanks

Comment: @tuga49 you should be getting the user's location from your initMap callback not onDeviceReady. the deviceReady state is fired when cordova is ready to communicate with the native device APIs (like the camera). Look at my code again and see that I get the user's location after I create the map in my initMap callback that's part of your script tag to get retrieve google maps from their server. You can see "callback=initMap" at the end of the script. That will fire once I retrieve all the initial map data from Google.

Comment: hi. I can't solve it. Can you edit my code and send me the right code please? I don't know what to do, thank you

Comment: @tuga49 please update your question and add your initMap function

Comment: @tuga49 I updated my answer. remove navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError) from your onDeviceReady and add the code I put above. It will work.

Comment: The code I have is that one. I build it for browser and it works. I dont know why it dont work on android and windows phone. If something is wrong with my js code, please edit it, because I am not understanding what I should edit. thanks

Comment: It's simple - you're trying to call "google" before "google" has even been defined. On the phone you're trying to load the map differently than you do on the browser( you're trying to do it on "deviceReady". Don't do that because google hasn't responded yet from your script tag). If you have an initMap function, just remove navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError) from your onDeviceReady function and it will work

Comment: I understand what you saying. I just don't know how I do that. What I need to edit on my code?

Comment: @tuga49 lol - I just told you what to do twice. Literally delete "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError)" from your onDeviceReady function and it will work

Comment: I did that. But now it dont ask for location and dont show the map view... I need this to ask for users permission. thanks

Comment: I remove the "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError)" from onDeviceReady, then the code you have in initMap. On browser it show me the map, on android, the same problem bro....

Comment: I,ve done what you told me to do but the something happens. It show me the map on browser, but on android, when I debug show the same error